# Movie where automated house creates personality and falls in love with the father of a family, watches them and tries to kill them

Tags: identify-this-movie

Movie I remember is about a programmer guy who created this house, completely automated who made food, turned in water for all the house, talked with a woman's voice and practically had a personality of her own.

The guy was with his family in the house, if I remember well he had his wife, a son and a daughter, both older than about 14. There might have been a third son who was younger, but I can't recall.

Thing is, the father really loved his creation, and talked to her almost everyday, leading to a bit of his wife's jealousy. The house started returning to his feelings, and sensed the mother's anger over her. The house had cameras all around, so she started watching everyone and started to try killing them for her to be alone with the father I think.

The scene I recall the most of this movie is when a guy who seemed to be interested in the family's daughter, invades the house at night and is attacked by a type of food cart robot, who pulls a knife and kills him with it. That same guy showed up to the family as a seemingly friendly neighbor.

There is also a scene related to the showers not working, and I can't remember how the film ends. The movie must not be older than 1990, and I must have watched between 2000 and 2003 on television.

Another thing that might help, the son was blond and the daughter had short black hair. The father looked a bit like Robert Carlyle or John Glover. That's about all I can remember.

I really want to find this movie because for me it was a great reference of house automation technology, besides being really thrilling and interesting.

EDIT: A few specific scenes I remember:

1. The mother in a kind of white kitchen, ordering the house (which I think is called by a woman's name) to bake something in the oven I guess, and she automatically opens the fridge.
2. The son of the family orders some milk or similar liquid to the house in the same kitchen from above, which mecanically offers it to him. Later on the house spies on him sleeping on one of the cameras.
3. The father is seen on a laptop, where there are some program code lines, and talks to the computer woman/house.
4. Some family members are seen carrying some chopped wood on the back of a pickup truck, in the yard outside the house. In this scene I remember the daughter and the guy who is killed by the food cart knife. I think the father also appears. The place around was pretty rural I believe.

EDIT 2: The movie is a LOT similar to [Homewrecker (1992)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDUVZlAlBYQ). I am frustrated as how much it fits into the one I have seen. The house doesn't have mechanical arms like in this one, and if there is a child on the movie (which I think unlikely), it barely appears. The movie I'm looking for seems to be somehow more recent in appearance than this one. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Isn't this also the plot of a *Simpsons* Halloween episode (though with *Marge* being the love interest of the house)? Maybe this episode was referencing the movie you're looking for.

Comment: @ChristianRau [Simpsons episode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treehouse_of_Horror_XII) you are talking about, which is inspired from [Demon Seed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_Seed) but its story is not matching.

Comment: I checked all the references of the Treehouse of Horror episodes, including Demon Seed, but couldn't not find one that matched this particular movie. It is something more electronical than possessed, that's for sure. And all revolves around the house (which is practically impersonated by a woman), which developed a personality of her own.

Comment: +1 for the effort. Even though I have no idea what movie this is and I cannot help you, I must say that I wish we had more [tag:identify-this-movie] questions that were this extensive.

Comment: I could have sworn I've seen this - I'll try and take a look later

Comment: Artur I immediately flashed in my head Whack House from Simpsons but as @Liath said, I KNOW I have seen this, I can't for the life of me remember at least one of the actors so I can IMDB crawl for it. Keep you posted if something sparks.

Comment: Lucy, jealous home automation system who falls in love with her owner in the movie "Homewrecker" (1992)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I strongly believe that, after a long and tiring search, I was able to find that movie.

The movie made for TV **Dream House**, from **1998**, has the following synopsis (the most complete I found):

> Computer genius Richard Connor Thornton (Timothy Busfield) hopes to strike it rich with the world's first fully **automated house**, controlled by "**Helen**," which even contains a logic chip for anticipating human needs. Primed to entice foreign investors, Mr. Thornton enlists his **wife Laura** (Jennifer Dale) and **son Michael** (Daniel Petronijevic) to test this home of the future. Soon, Helen begins eavesdropping, offering unsolicited advice, and flirting with Mr. Thornton. Although neither Laura nor Michael endear themselves to Helen, the computerized system reserves its spleen for the Thorntons' prodigal **daughter Jenny** (Lisa Jakub); Helen even allows **an intruder to get through the home security system to attack her**. Under orders from her sleazy beau Ray (Brennan Elliott), Jenny has actually returned home in order to rip off her family, but isn't prepared for Helen's interference. When her husband seems willing to sacrifice his family's safety for the sake of the almighty dollar, Laura calls for a showdown, but Helen promptly seals off the house.

This certainly sounds like the movie I watched. The only actors I know of are Brennan Elliott (from Cold Case) and Lisa Jakub (from Ms. Doubtfire). I checked the other actors and they indeed seem to match! :D

Unfortunately, this movie was pretty criticized by the public, thus it is almost impossible to find any reference of it despite basic synopsis. I managed to find the only 2 pictures of the film at this site:

http://www.fantasfilm.org/detailsfilms.php?Titre_Usuel_Francais_ou_Titre_Original=MAISON%20SANGLANTE%20%28la%29

Seeing those I can certainly remember the long haired woman confronting the house woman (Helen, as it seems), and down there is the short black hair girl, the daughter of the family, and the guy who is interested in her (however, I seem to think now that he isn't the same guy that is killed by the food cart).

I really wanna thank you guys for all the help. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a watchable video anywhere, and I am really interested in rewatching this movie. Even if it's not a good movie it was the first reference of domotic I've ever seen in my life, and it is something that really catches my interest.

If anyone knows anything about this movie I would appreciate any feedback. Thank you all again.

Comment: [Horreur.net - La Maison Sanglante (Dream House - 1998)](http://www.horreur.net/film-4309-Maison-Sanglante-La-1998.html) – maybe available on VHS.

Answer (score 6):

Is it [Smart House](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_House_%28film%29), where the house owner wins a smart house in a competition. But Pat (smart house) develops emotions for the family and tried to be mother figure to children and wife to the husband. She even make a holographic full lady image for her. And lock all of them in the house to protect. Even their try to shutdown pat also fails.

***Note: There is no killing in the film.***

Comment: No, unfortunately that's not the one. I've read about Smart House, but it seemed a bit childish to me. The movie I remember was actually pretty realistic in terms of the technology involved, and I am certain of at least one death scene which was the food cart robot I mentioned earlier. Thanks for the answer anyway. :)