Can you give me a title of this sci-fi home security movie?
Many years ago (during 1995-2000) I saw this movie on HBO. The story goes like this, 
A man sets home security in his home for protection. The protection system is based on the AI (artificial intelligence). i.e. when his wife went into bathroom, the shower automatically gets started. His daughter brings her boyfriend and System automatically creates file of her boyfriend, based on the talks they do. 
There are spiders robots in the movie which works as room cleaner. 
Later there is some malfunction in the system and then that man try to shutdown this automated system. 
Movie is in english language.
Can you please help me to find the title of this movie ?
It is not the movie suggested by ankit in below comment.

Go though this similar question http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/16446/movie-where-automated-house-creates-personality-and-falls-in-love-with-the-fathe/16666#16666

@AnkitSharma, I download that movie, but its not the same movie, I am looking for, however story is bit same.

Have you checked if chaitanya89's answer is correct yet?

@CrowTRobot, Yes, I download that movie too, but its not the same.

Could this be Runaway (1984)
Plot:

The film is set in the near future, where robots are commonplace – a part of everyday life like any other electrical appliance, and are just as prone to malfunctions. But when a robot malfunctions it could pose a threat to people or property. Such robots are known as "runaways". Since they are more dangerous than the average machine, they are handled by a division of the police trained in robotics. The "runaway" squad, however, is treated as an easy and unexciting assignment, often ridiculed.


Thanks for the answer, I need to download and watch this movie. I think this is bit old movie. What I asked is movies of 90s. No problem. I will watch your movie too. Thanks.

@user2060383 Trailer of this movie is available at YouTube. Give it a try.
